# Server Error 500 when trying to add instance of a model on Django

Tags: python, django, server

I have a website working perfectly in Django for me, I can add and delete instances of models as I want. However, if someone else tries to add an instance with the exact same admin account, the page shows "Server Error 500".

I am using the default SQLite settings for django.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Receita(models.Model):
    titulo_receita = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    resumo_receita = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    tempo_receita = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='');
    rendimento_receita = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='');
    imagem_preview = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/', default='static/default_image.png')
    conteudo_receita = models.TextField();
    data_receita = models.DateTimeField('Data publicação', default=datetime.now());

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo_receita;

class Produto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    desc = models.TextField()
    # desc = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='');
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/', default='static/default_image.png')

    info1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    cod1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    info2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    cod2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    info3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    cod3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome;
```

**admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Receita
from .models import Produto
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE
from django.db import models

# Register your models here.

class ReceitaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE()}
    }

admin.site.register(Receita, ReceitaAdmin)
admin.site.register(Produto)
```

Comment: Check the log / console output for the error traceback and add it to your question!

Comment: Where can I find the log?

Comment: How did you run Django?

Comment: Django is running with FastCGI

Comment: Then it depends on your deployment and configuration where the logs are.